# How to parse logrotate.conf file in linux using python

Tags: python, logrotate

I am trying to uncomment a string using regular expression in logrotate config file, which is uncommenting all lines which has the string available.

```sh
# create new (empty) log files after rotating old ones
#create
```

In my case i m trying to uncomment 'create' from above. which is uncommenting both the lines.

```py
output_lines = []
lines = self.readFile(LOGROTATE_CONFIG_FILE)
for line in lines:
    if not re.search(r'\b' + str + r'\b', line):
        output_lines.append(line)
    else:
        if line.startswith('#'):
            l = re.sub(r'^ *#', '', line)
            output_lines.append(l)
        else:
            output_lines.append(line)
if len(output_lines) > 0:
    self.writeFile(LOGROTATE_CONFIG_FILE, output_lines)
```

Comment: So, are you trying to uncomment the second line and not the first one?

Comment: @Anwarvic yes i am trying to comment 2nd line

Comment: change the regex to be `^#` instead of `^ *#`. In this way, the second line will be **uncommented** and the first line will be the same